# how to transfer CLOB data from one database to another remote ORACLE database having DBLinks

Tags: oracle, clob

The problem is, how to transfer CLOB data from one source database to another Oracle database, having DBLinks.

Oracle cannot transfer CLOB data using DBLinks so what kind of solution we can have apart from: extending fields in Oracle to Varchar2 32.767 characters (new feature of Oracle 12).

Comment: I thought that limitation applies to the deprecated `LONG` columns, not to `CLOB` columns?

Answer (score 1):

At first you need temporary table:

```
create global temporary table TBL_TMP_CLOB
(
  c_clob CLOB
)
```

At second use 'Insert from Select':

```
INSERT INTO schema.remote_table@dblink(rem_clob) SELECT * FROM TBL_TMP_CLOB;
```

Comment: What should this global temporary table store?

Comment: @Sylwia Krakowska temporary table shoud store CLOB data, which you want to transfer to remote DB

Comment: I cannot explain correctly why it works, but I use this method in my projects.

Comment: so temporary table should be created on the source sidem, is it?

Comment: @Sylwia Krakowska yes, it is. I think this [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=insert-in-blob-with-dblink) could hepl you.

Answer (score 0):

I released a Github project that queries CLOBs and BLOBs over a dblink.
https://github.com/HowdPrescott/Lob_Over_DBLink

Here's the CLOB part in a stand alone function:

```
create or replace function dblink_clob(
    p_dblink    in varchar2
  , p_clob_col  in varchar2
  , p_rid       in urowid
)
return clob is
    /**  A function to fetch a CLOB column over a dblink  **/
    /**  Laurence Prescott 25-Aug-17  **/
    /**  select dblink_clob('some_dblink', 'some_clob_column', rowid)
           from some_table@some_dblink;
         Note: Does not work on tables that have a virtual column (eg. xmltype).
    **/

    c_chunk_size    constant pls_integer := 4000;
    v_chunk         varchar2(4000);
    v_remote_table  varchar2(128);
    v_clob          clob;
    v_pos           pls_integer := 1;
begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_clob, true, dbms_lob.call);
    execute immediate 'select object_name from user_objects@' ||p_dblink
                   || ' where data_object_id = dbms_rowid.rowid_object(:bv_rid) '
    into v_remote_table using cast (p_rid as rowid);
    loop
        execute immediate 
            'select dbms_lob.substr@' ||p_dblink|| '(' ||p_clob_col|| ', ' ||c_chunk_size
         || ', ' ||v_pos|| ') from ' ||v_remote_table|| '@' ||p_dblink|| ' where rowid = :rid '
        into v_chunk using p_rid;
        begin dbms_lob.append(v_clob, v_chunk);
        exception when others then
            if sqlcode = -6502 then exit; else raise; end if;
        end;
        if length(v_chunk) < c_chunk_size then exit; end if;
        v_pos := v_pos + c_chunk_size;
    end loop;
    return v_clob;
end dblink_clob;
```

I think the example is fairly self explanatory, but here's a bit of a description.
The function relies on the fact that you can call functions/procedures on a remote DB across a dblink - in this case *dbms_lob.substr()*.
First it finds the remote table name by using its object id (which is encoded into the *rowid*). That saves having to pass the remote table name in as another parameter.
Note also that the p_rid parameter is a *urowid*, as it's a *rowid* from the remote DB. That's why it needs to be cast.
Then the CLOB is extracted and rebuilt in 4000 byte chunks, which is the maximum varchar2 size in PL/SQL. These chunks are varchar2's and can be passed across the dblink.
The *if length(v_chunk) < c_chunk_size ...* clause is satisfied after the last of the CLOB has been read (then the "chunk" buffer won't be filled).
The exception catch for *ORA-06502* is needed when the length of the CLOB is a multiple of 4000, then the "if" clause is not satisfied, even though there is no more data.
You could just rely on this catch and remove the "if" clause altogether. But I did some performance testing and found that in most cases it's better to leave it in.

Answer (score 0):

Howd probably had the correct way to do it 4 years ago, but I needed to update his to something like the following to get it to work (I simplified his for my own use, so the following might not compile or work, but you get the idea, the first query isn't needed anymore in 12.1.0.2.0):

```
create or replace function dblink_clob(
    p_dblink    in varchar2
  , v_remote_table in varchar2
  , p_clob_col  in varchar2
  , p_rid       in urowid
)
return clob is
    /**  A function to fetch a CLOB column over a dblink  **/
    /**  Laurence Prescott 25-Aug-17  **/
    /**  select dblink_clob('some_dblink', 'some_clob_column', rowid)
           from some_table@some_dblink;
         Note: Does not work on tables that have a virtual column (eg. xmltype).
    **/

    c_chunk_size    constant pls_integer := 4000;
    v_chunk         varchar2(4000);
    v_clob          clob;
    v_pos           pls_integer := 1;
begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_clob, true, dbms_lob.call);
    loop
        execute immediate 
            'select dbms_lob.substr@' ||p_dblink|| '(' ||p_clob_col|| ', ' ||c_chunk_size
         || ', ' ||v_pos|| ') from ' ||v_remote_table|| '@' ||p_dblink|| ' where rowid = :rid '
        into v_chunk using p_rid;
        begin dbms_lob.append(v_clob, v_chunk);
        exception when others then
            if sqlcode = -6502 then exit; else raise; end if;
        end;
        if length(v_chunk) < c_chunk_size then exit; end if;
        v_pos := v_pos + c_chunk_size;
    end loop;
    return v_clob;
end dblink_clob;
```