# Moving clob columns between 2 databases using dB link

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

Here we have to move `clob` columns along with other columns in a single statement in oracle like

```
Insert into table_name@dblink (other_data_type_columns , clob_columns)
Select other_data_type_columns , clob_columns from table_2@dblink;
```

Is this possible ,and we have only one area where we have `db_links` . Please suggest if Incase any alternatives exist

Comment: Please help required

Comment: solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014390/how-to-transfer-clob-data-from-one-database-to-another-remote-oracle-database-ha

Answer (score 0):

Make a view of that SELECT Query and then execute same statement.
you can use select Query as Remote Query also.

Comment: The table structure remains the same in both of the structure